# Can activiti be used to develop a state machine?

Tags: java

The aim is to build a state machine in java which has

1. An initial state and which can make transition based on a given target state id.
2. It can output a set of possible transitions which can be reached from the target state id.
3. It can be achieved by simple coding but i want the workflow to be configurable.

This requires some work. I wanted to know if there is an existing library in java which does this. I came across [`activiti`](http://www.activiti.org/userguide/) but i don't know how to use it for my scenario. If it can be used for the scenario, please mention exact steps needed to configure it for the same. Or if there is any other alternative for this.

Answer (score 0):

Given your requirements, I'm not sure Activiti is a good fit, since it is a full blown workflow engine, with users/groups, a modeling application, and a set of existing processes.

I'd probably look at specialized state machine like: https://github.com/oxo42/stateless4j

Answer (score 0):

Two more open-source state machine library you can use

1) SCXML(State Chart XML): http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-scxml/guide.html

2) Spring state machine：http://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle